# JQuery: Focus shifts from one radio check button to another

Tags: jquery, radio-button, focus

Hi I'm doing homework for a JQuery assignment. The focus highlighting is supposed to shift from one input to another every time the user clicks the submit button and one input section is completed but not the next and/or the rest.

My issue stems from the third input section, which is a radio-button input instead of a text input. There are two radio-buttons check circles for the users to click, one for the male gender and the other for the female gender, but they are only supposed to click only one in order from the focus to shift to the dropdown list section despite the fact that there is an input section for both radio-button check circles in the html.

My question is, how do I write the JQuery code in such a way that the focus will shift to the dropdown list after only one of the radio-buttons are clicked instead of both. My code for the html and the Javascript/Jquery is included below:

```
Code:`enter code here`

HTML:

    <form>
        <br>
        <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" required> <span class="error" id="first_error"></span>
        <br>
        <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" required> <span class="error" id="last_error"></span>
        <br>
        Male <input type="radio" name="gender" value="M">
        Female <input type="radio" name="gender" value="F"> <span class="error" id="gender_error"></span>
        <br>

Javascript/JQuery

$(document).ready(function() { //document ready function to contain jquery code


$('body').css("background-color", "tan").css("padding-left", "50px");
$('h1').css("font-size", "300%");
$('h3').css("font-size", "200%");
$('input').css("margin", "10px");

var myFirstName = $("#first_name").val();
var myLastName = $("#last_name").val();

$("#first_name").focus();
$("#first_error").text("You must Enter a First Name").hide();
$("#last_error").text("You must Enter a Last Name").hide();

$(".error").css("color", "red");

$("input").change(function() {
  var myFormChange = $(this).closest('form').find(':input');
  myFormChange.eq( myFormChange.index(this) + 1 ).focus();

});

$("#mysubmit").click(function(){




    if (myFirstName == '')
    {
$("#first_error").text("You must Enter a First Name");
    }
    else {
        if (myFirstName !== '')
        {
            $("#first_error").text("");
        }
    }

});

});
// end of "document ready" jquery code.[imageofinputfocus][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2UT6.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to check the name of the input.  If it has the same name, thus you clicked the first radio button of the two, then skip past it.

```
var nextElement = myFormChange.eq( myFormChange.index(this) + 1 );

if (nextElement.attr('name') === this.name) {
    nextElement = myFormChange.eq( myFormChange.index(this) + 2 );
}

nextElement.focus();
```